# Неправильно при нажатии на энтер выводиться попап

Tags: javascript, html, css

При нажатии на кнопку все выводится корректно(попап с надписью правильно\не правильно)
а если нажать на поле input то тогда все время будет вылезать попап "не правильно" даже если ответ правильный.

```js
// сложение
const addition = document.querySelector('.addition'),
    additionInput = addition.querySelector('.addition > input'),
    additionBtn = addition.querySelector('.addition-btn'),
    numAddition1 = addition.querySelector('.num__addition-1'),
    numAddition2 = addition.querySelector('.num__addition-2');


// вычитание
const subtraction = document.querySelector('.subtraction'),
    subtractionInput = subtraction.querySelector('.subtraction > input'),
    subtractionBtn = subtraction.querySelector('.subtraction-btn'),
    numSubtraction1 = subtraction.querySelector('.num__subtraction-1'),
    numSubtraction2 = subtraction.querySelector('.num__subtraction-2');

// умножение
const multiplication = document.querySelector('.multiplication'),
    multiplicationInput = multiplication.querySelector('.multiplication > input'),
    numMultiplication1 = multiplication.querySelector('.num__multiplication-1'),
    numMultiplication2 = multiplication.querySelector('.num__multiplication-2'),
    multiplicationBtn = multiplication.querySelector('.multiplication-btn');

// попап
const popupMask = document.querySelector('.popup-mask'),
    popupInfo = popupMask.querySelector('.popup-info'),
    popup = popupMask.querySelector('.popup');


popupMask.addEventListener('click', function () {
    popupMask.classList.add('hidden');
});

function successAnswer() {
    popupMask.classList.remove('hidden');
    popupMask.classList.add('show');
    popupInfo.innerHTML = 'Правильно, молодец!';
    popup.classList.remove('errorOption');
    popup.classList.add('successOption');
    setTimeout(() => {
        location.reload();
    }, 3000);
    popupMask.addEventListener('click', function () {
        location.reload();
    });
}

function errorAnswer() {
    popupMask.classList.remove('hidden');
    popupMask.classList.add('show');
    popupInfo.innerHTML = 'Не правильно, <br/>Подумай еще.';
    popup.classList.add('errorOption');
    setTimeout(() => {
        popupMask.classList.add('hidden');
    }, 3000);
}





function enterBtn(btn, input, res) {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            // моя 1я попытка - не получилась
            btn.click();


            // моя 2я попытка - не получилась
            if (res == input.value) {
                return successAnswer();
            } else {
                return errorAnswer();
            }

            // моя 3я попытка - не получилась
            if (res !== input.value) {

                return errorAnswer();
            } else {
                return successAnswer(); 
            }


            // моя 4я попытка - не получилась
            if (res == input.value) {
                btn.click();
                successAnswer();
            } else if(res == input.value) {
                btn.click();
                errorAnswer();
            }

        }
    });
}



// сложение
function randomNumberAddition() {
    let n1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    let n2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    let res = n1 + n2;
    numAddition1.innerHTML = n1;
    numAddition2.innerHTML = n2;

    let num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    let num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);



    additionBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (res == additionInput.value) {
            successAnswer();
        } else {
            errorAnswer();
        }
    });
    let answer = document.querySelector('.answer__addition');
    answer.onclick = function () {
        answer.innerHTML = res;
    };
    enterBtn(additionBtn, additionInput, res);
    console.log(res);
}
randomNumberAddition();



// вычитание
function randomNumberSubtraction() {
    let n1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 196);
    let n2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 13);
    let res = n1 - n2;
    numSubtraction1.innerHTML = n1;
    numSubtraction2.innerHTML = n2;
    subtractionBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (res == subtractionInput.value) {
            successAnswer();
        } else {
            errorAnswer();
        }
    });
    let answer = document.querySelector('.answer__subtraction');
    answer.onclick = function () {
        answer.innerHTML = res;
    };
    enterBtn(subtractionBtn, subtractionInput, res);
    console.log(res);
}
randomNumberSubtraction();



// умножение
function randomNumberMultiplication() {
    let n1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1);
    let n2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1);
    let res = n1 * n2;
    numMultiplication1.innerHTML = n1;
    numMultiplication2.innerHTML = n2;
    multiplicationBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (res == multiplicationInput.value) {
            successAnswer();
        } else {
            errorAnswer();
        }
    });
    let answer = document.querySelector('.answer__multiplication');
    answer.onclick = function () {
        answer.innerHTML = res;
    };
    enterBtn(multiplicationBtn, multiplicationInput, res);
    console.log(res);
}
randomNumberMultiplication();
```

```css
.answer--style {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgb(18, 185, 93);
    display: inline-block;
}

.answer--style img {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.answer--style img:hover {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(144, 43, 226);
}

.answer--style:hover {
    color: rgb(18, 185, 93);
}

.popup-mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.623);


    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .3s linear;
}

.popup-mask.show {
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: .3s linear;
}

.popup-mask.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .3s linear;
}

.popup {
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    border-radius: 43% 57% 62% 38% / 27% 49% 51% 73%;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 66%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;


    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px #000000, inset 4px 4px 15px 0px #000000, 4px 1px 15px 5px rgba(79, 255, 80, 0);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px #000000, inset 4px 4px 15px 0px #000000, 4px 1px 15px 5px rgba(79, 255, 80, 0);


    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 5px 50px 50px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 50px 50px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); */
}

.popup.successOption {
    background-image: linear-gradient(5deg,
            hsl(171deg 75% 28%) 0%,
            hsl(164deg 100% 27%) 24%,
            hsl(153deg 100% 29%) 35%,
            hsl(135deg 81% 34%) 45%,
            hsl(139deg 81% 38%) 55%,
            hsl(160deg 100% 40%) 65%,
            hsl(171deg 100% 45%) 76%,
            hsl(179deg 100% 50%) 100%);
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.popup.errorOption {
    background-image: linear-gradient(345deg,
            hsl(0deg 85% 35%) 0%,
            hsl(322deg 100% 23%) 33%,
            hsl(321deg 100% 27%) 67%,
            hsl(0deg 78% 51%) 100%);
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;

}

.popup-info {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="popup-mask">
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="popup-info">jfeor</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- сложение -->
    <div class="addition">
        <span class="num__addition-1"></span>
        <span>+</span>
        <span class="num__addition-2"></span>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" class="addition-btn" value="Ответить">
    </form>


        <div class="answer__addition answer--style"><img src="img/answer.png" alt="Watch"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- вычитание -->
    <div class="subtraction">
        <span class="num__subtraction-1"></span>
        <span>-</span>
        <span class="num__subtraction-2"></span>
        <input type="text">
        <button class="subtraction-btn">Ответить</button>
        <div class="answer__subtraction answer--style"><img src="img/answer.png" alt="Watch"></div>

    </div>

    <!-- умножение -->
    <div class="multiplication">
        <span class="num__multiplication-1"></span>
        <span>*</span>
        <span class="num__multiplication-2"></span>
        <input type="text">
        <button type="submit" class="multiplication-btn">Ответить</button>
        <div class="answer__multiplication answer--style"><img src="img/answer.png" alt="Watch"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ты хочешь, чтобы по нажатию Enter проверялся конкретный пример? Тогда надо отслеживать и обрабатывать нажатие на конкретном инпуте. Сейчас у тебя нормально работает, если все поля заполнены верно. А если введено правильное значение на сложении, например, и остальные поля не заполнены - вылазит ошибка.

Comment: Привет, я гуглил но так и не получилось разобраться с этим.... Можно маленький пример как отслеживать конкретный инпут?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// сложение
    const addition = document.querySelector('.addition'),
        additionInput = addition.querySelector('.addition > input'),
        additionBtn = addition.querySelector('.addition-btn'),
        numAddition1 = addition.querySelector('.num__addition-1'),
        numAddition2 = addition.querySelector('.num__addition-2');


    // вычитание
    const subtraction = document.querySelector('.subtraction'),
        subtractionInput = subtraction.querySelector('.subtraction > input'),
        subtractionBtn = subtraction.querySelector('.subtraction-btn'),
        numSubtraction1 = subtraction.querySelector('.num__subtraction-1'),
        numSubtraction2 = subtraction.querySelector('.num__subtraction-2');

    // умножение
    const multiplication = document.querySelector('.multiplication'),
        multiplicationInput = multiplication.querySelector('.multiplication > input'),
        numMultiplication1 = multiplication.querySelector('.num__multiplication-1'),
        numMultiplication2 = multiplication.querySelector('.num__multiplication-2'),
        multiplicationBtn = multiplication.querySelector('.multiplication-btn');

    // попап
    const popupMask = document.querySelector('.popup-mask'),
        popupInfo = popupMask.querySelector('.popup-info'),
        popup = popupMask.querySelector('.popup');


    popupMask.addEventListener('click', function () {
        popupMask.classList.add('hidden');
    });

    function successAnswer() {
        popupMask.classList.remove('hidden');
        popupMask.classList.add('show');
        popupInfo.innerHTML = 'Правильно, молодец!';
        popup.classList.remove('errorOption');
        popup.classList.add('successOption');
        setTimeout(() => {
            location.reload();
        }, 3000);
        popupMask.addEventListener('click', function () {
            location.reload();
        });
    }

    function errorAnswer() {
        popupMask.classList.remove('hidden');
        popupMask.classList.add('show');
        popupInfo.innerHTML = 'Не правильно, <br/>Подумай еще.';
        popup.classList.add('errorOption');
        setTimeout(() => {
            popupMask.classList.add('hidden');
        }, 3000);
    }





    function enterBtn(btn, input, res) {
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                // моя 1я попытка - не получилась
                btn.click();


                // моя 2я попытка - не получилась
                if (res == input.value) {
                    return successAnswer();
                } else {
                    return errorAnswer();
                }

                // моя 3я попытка - не получилась
                if (res !== input.value) {

                    return errorAnswer();
                } else {
                    return successAnswer(); 
                }


                // моя 4я попытка - не получилась
                if (res == input.value) {
                    btn.click();
                    successAnswer();
                } else if(res == input.value) {
                    btn.click();
                    errorAnswer();
                }

            }
        });
    }



    // сложение
    function randomNumberAddition() {
        let n1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let n2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let res = n1 + n2;
        numAddition1.innerHTML = n1;
        numAddition2.innerHTML = n2;

        let num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);



        additionBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (res == additionInput.value) {
                successAnswer();
            } else {
                errorAnswer();
            }
        });
        let answer = document.querySelector('.answer__addition');
        answer.onclick = function () {
            answer.innerHTML = res;
        };
    //    enterBtn(additionBtn, additionInput, res);
      additionInput.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.keyCode == 13) additionBtn.click();
          });
            
        console.log(res);
    }
    randomNumberAddition();



    // вычитание
    function randomNumberSubtraction() {
        let n1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 196);
        let n2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 13);
        let res = n1 - n2;
        numSubtraction1.innerHTML = n1;
        numSubtraction2.innerHTML = n2;
        subtractionBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (res == subtractionInput.value) {
                successAnswer();
            } else {
                errorAnswer();
            }
        });
        let answer = document.querySelector('.answer__subtraction');
        answer.onclick = function () {
            answer.innerHTML = res;
        };
    //    enterBtn(subtractionBtn, subtractionInput, res);
    subtractionInput.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.keyCode == 13) subtractionBtn.click();
          });
        console.log(res);
    }
    randomNumberSubtraction();



    // умножение
    function randomNumberMultiplication() {
        let n1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1);
        let n2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1);
        let res = n1 * n2;
        numMultiplication1.innerHTML = n1;
        numMultiplication2.innerHTML = n2;
        multiplicationBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (res == multiplicationInput.value) {
                successAnswer();
            } else {
                errorAnswer();
            }
        });
        let answer = document.querySelector('.answer__multiplication');
        answer.onclick = function () {
            answer.innerHTML = res;
        };
    //    enterBtn(multiplicationBtn, multiplicationInput, res);
    multiplicationInput.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.keyCode == 13) multiplicationBtn.click();
          });
        console.log(res);
    }
    randomNumberMultiplication();
```

```css
.answer--style {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgb(18, 185, 93);
    display: inline-block;
}

.answer--style img {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.answer--style img:hover {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(144, 43, 226);
}

.answer--style:hover {
    color: rgb(18, 185, 93);
}

.popup-mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.623);


    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .3s linear;
}

.popup-mask.show {
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: .3s linear;
}

.popup-mask.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .3s linear;
}

.popup {
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    border-radius: 43% 57% 62% 38% / 27% 49% 51% 73%;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 66%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;


    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px #000000, inset 4px 4px 15px 0px #000000, 4px 1px 15px 5px rgba(79, 255, 80, 0);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px #000000, inset 4px 4px 15px 0px #000000, 4px 1px 15px 5px rgba(79, 255, 80, 0);


    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 5px 50px 50px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 50px 50px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); */
}

.popup.successOption {
    background-image: linear-gradient(5deg,
            hsl(171deg 75% 28%) 0%,
            hsl(164deg 100% 27%) 24%,
            hsl(153deg 100% 29%) 35%,
            hsl(135deg 81% 34%) 45%,
            hsl(139deg 81% 38%) 55%,
            hsl(160deg 100% 40%) 65%,
            hsl(171deg 100% 45%) 76%,
            hsl(179deg 100% 50%) 100%);
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.popup.errorOption {
    background-image: linear-gradient(345deg,
            hsl(0deg 85% 35%) 0%,
            hsl(322deg 100% 23%) 33%,
            hsl(321deg 100% 27%) 67%,
            hsl(0deg 78% 51%) 100%);
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;

}

.popup-info {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="popup-mask">
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="popup-info">jfeor</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- сложение -->
    <div class="addition">
        <span class="num__addition-1"></span>
        <span>+</span>
        <span class="num__addition-2"></span>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" class="addition-btn" value="Ответить">
    </form>


        <div class="answer__addition answer--style"><img src="img/answer.png" alt="Watch"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- вычитание -->
    <div class="subtraction">
        <span class="num__subtraction-1"></span>
        <span>-</span>
        <span class="num__subtraction-2"></span>
        <input type="text">
        <button class="subtraction-btn">Ответить</button>
        <div class="answer__subtraction answer--style"><img src="img/answer.png" alt="Watch"></div>

    </div>

    <!-- умножение -->
    <div class="multiplication">
        <span class="num__multiplication-1"></span>
        <span>*</span>
        <span class="num__multiplication-2"></span>
        <input type="text">
        <button type="submit" class="multiplication-btn">Ответить</button>
        <div class="answer__multiplication answer--style"><img src="img/answer.png" alt="Watch"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Но я бы лучше сделал одну кнопку на все три примера, соответственно и проверку всех трех примеров сразу. Иначе возможна неправильная работа. Например, в примерах на сложение и вычитание даны неправильные ответы, на умножение правильный. Enter нажат на умножение - результат "Правильно". Неправильные ответы проигнорированы.

Comment: Либо, остаются кнопки на каждом примере, но добавляется отметка, что ответ обработан и засчитан/отвергнут (например, классические "галочка/крестик")..

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, понял)